# cmd returns "cannot find the path specified" for only some files in a folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, path, directory, command-prompt

I'm trying to write a batch file to rename all files in a series of folders.

Each line has the format [path]"old file name" "new file name"

For some files it works fine, but on other files *in the same folder* it returns "the system cannot find the path specified," even though the path is exactly the same.

Edit: for example, one line in the batch file is

```
ren U:\JohnSmith\Portfolio\"08805_09282010_094346_10452467.PDF" "3rd Quarter Report"
```

and it throws the error, while another line

```
ren U:\JohnSmith\Portfolio\"08805_03082011_101040_17279080.PDF" "4th Quarter Report"
```

renamed the file fine, even though the paths are identical.

Comment: did you check the extension?

Comment: yes, both the original file and the destination file are .pdf

Comment: try to copy and paste the full path to your search bar, see it finds the file, I am guessing you may miss some `space`

Comment: Yes, I paste the path into the bar and it opens the .pdf file no problem

Comment: ***Show Actual Code***

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43053786/edit) and post what did you tried as code until now !

Comment: If there is an error, please copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: First, use `ren "U:\JohnSmith\Portfolio\08805_09282010_094346_10452467.PDF" "3rd Quarter Report"`. The double quotes should enclose the entire file specification, i.e. drive, path, file name and file extension, and not just parts of it. Second, make sure your batch file is saved as ANSI file (1 byte per character encoded file) and not as UTF-8 encoded Unicode file. Second, a PDF file can't be renamed while currently opened in Adobe Reader because Adobe Reader opens the PDF file with a read/write lock for other applications (exclusive mode).

Comment: Third, text output into a console window on running a batch file from within a command prompt window (strongly recommended, double clicking batch file is not good for debugging a batch file) or executing commands manually can be copied to clipboard by right clicking into console window to open context menu and left clicking on first context menu item __Mark__. Then a rectangular selection can be made with mouse (pointing stick, touch pad, ...) and finally hitting key RETURN copies the selected text to clipboard.

Comment: Thank you but none of the suggestions have solved the issue. The problem doesn't seem to be with the batch file itself, because I've already tried executing commands manually copying individual lines and pasting into command prompt, and some lines throw the "system cannot find the path specified" error while others in the same directory do not, even though the path has not changed.

Comment: I resolved the issue, some of the destination file names had a "/" in their name, I thought putting the new file name in quotes would make it accept it, but once I changed all the slashes to dashes all of the files were renamed.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue, some of the destination file names had a "/" in their name, I thought putting the new file name in quotes would make it accept it, but once I changed all the slashes to dashes all of the files were renamed.

So

```
ren "U:\JohnSmith\8804_3598_3987" "11/12 3rd Quarter"
```

Threw the "system could not find the path" error, but

```
ren "U:\JohnSmith\8804_3598_3987" "11-12 3rd Quarter"
```

did not.